# Using Awk to print the unavailable record only once

Tags: linux, if-statement, awk

I am writing an awk script which looks like this inside:

```
awk -v searchValue="$searchValue" '{ if ($3 == searchValue){
                                                    printf NR".", $1, $2, $3, $4                                          
                                     }
                                     else if ($3!=searchValue) {print "The value that you entered is not available. Please try again."}                                                                      
                                     }' file
```

This is my file.

```
One Two 20 100
Three Four 10 500
Five Six 30 800
Seven Eight 20 500
```

This tries to print the else if method once, but instead, it prints for all of the lines that do not include the searched value.
If I entered 20, my output looks like this:

```
1. One  Two  20 100
The value that you entered is not available. Please try again.
The value that you entered is not available. Please try again.
4. Four Five 20 500
```

I have to use the awk command to print else if output once. Let's say if I entered 700. How do I fix it to get this:

```
The value that you entered is not available. Please try again.
```

Comment: Your code would be easier to read if you didn't indent it by 30 characters (or however many that is) thereby requiring a scroll bar to see it. Also, never use `printf foo` for any `foo` that can contain input data, e.g. `$1`, as that'll fail cryptically when the input contains printf formatting characters, always use `printf "%s", foo` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a solution using the `END` clause? You can set a variable if you find a match, and then use an `if` in the `END` to print the message only if no matches are found.

```
awk -v searchValue="$searchValue" '
  $3 == searchValue { ismatch = 1; print NR".", $0; }
  END { 
    if(!ismatch) print "The value that you entered is not available. Please try again." 
  }' file
```

Also I'm not sure you really want to be using `printf`... plain old `print` seems a better fit here. And `$0` is a little easier than listing out `$1, $2, $3, $4`.

Comment: thanks david. u really helped me a lot